# AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'objects', breaking the query attributes

Tags: django-models, django-views

I have error after making "double query" request in my views.py how could I easily get around this problem ?

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
    index= request.POST.get('dropdown_index')
    stocks= Indexes.objects.filter(Symbol=index)

Open = stocks.objects.values("Open")
High = stocks.objects.values("High")
Close = stocks.objects.values("Close")
Low = stocks.objects.values("Low")
```

```
 mysite\main\views.py", line 18, in HomeView
 Open = stocks.objects.values("Open")
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'objects'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `stocks` is already a `QuerySet`, so you can obtain the values with:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    index = request.POST.get('dropdown_index')
    stocks = Indexes.objects.filter(Symbol=index)
    Open = stocks.values("Open")
    High = stocks.values("High")
    Close = stocks.values("Close")
    Low = stocks.values("Low")
```

This will however make *four* queries to the database, you can fetch the values for `Open`, `High`, `Close` and `Low` all in the same query from the database:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    index = request.POST.get('dropdown_index')
    stocks = Indexes.objects.filter(Symbol=index)
    data = stocks.values("Open", "High", "Close", "Low")
```